# ORM for python that does not require we to define all properties for classes for database tables

Tags: python, database, orm

I have access to a large database system. I would like to talk with it in an efficient manner.

Are there ORM framework like SQLAlchemy (I know SQLAlchemy) that does not require we to define all properties for classes for each database tables?

Because the database is already there, my aim is to avoid creating properties for classes.

Comment: How would an Object Relation Mapper work without objects?

Comment: @LarryLustig - I believe the nuance here is that the OP would like not to have a calss _for each table_... Puzzling concept - but different than refusing the idea of objects altogether...

Comment: Still not sure what that means.  An ORM saves objects to a database, each object must be an instance of a class.  Do you think it means saving arbitrary objects not derived from an ORM class?  Or just skipping classes for the tables you don't want to use?  Such things could exist but I have no idea what the user is really asking.

Comment: @LarryLustig: I think OP wants a framework that will dynamically generate classes using database introspection.  OP did not say "does not require classes for each table", but "does not require *we define* classes for each table".

Comment: @LarryLustig Sorry for confusion. I want to avoid coding all properties for classes manually, since the database have tables with more number of fields.  I have edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Using SQLAlchemy's introspection features you can easily enough have a metaclass that gives you a new mapped class given a table name.  The class still has to be defined, but ***you*** don't have to define it.

```
def introspect(tablename, *mapper_args, **mapper_kwargs):
  u'given a table name and optional mapper arguments return an ORM class'
  global metadata  # or pass it in, or use OO, whatever
  global engine    # or pass it in, or use OO, whatever
  table = sqlalchemy.Table(tablename, metadata,
      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
  class DynamicClass: pass  # you can provide nice __init__, __str__ methods
  return sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(DynamicClass, table,
      *mapper_args, **mapper_kwargs)
```

Hibernate has a similar introspection feature, but it generates Java source files, and therefore is a build-time, not run-time, operation.